# input error in Java program

Tags: java

Error in following code-

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Unhandled exception type IOException
```

---

```
import java.io.*;
public class Inp {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int number = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        System.out.println("Number = " + number);

    }

 }
```

Comment: always compile your program first

Comment: @ Webroots, Why you tagged into **java-me**?

Comment: @bharath ..or [tag:swing] or [tag:java-ee]?

Comment: all of the specific tags are unrelated ... replace them by something related to your question (possibly including "homework-at-last-minute-without-wanting-to-read-the-textbook") ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The method [readLine](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html#readLine%28%29) can throw an `IOException` which is a checked exception.

Because of [The Catch or Specify Requirement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html) you must either catch this exception or specify that your method throws this exception.

> Code that fails to honor the Catch or Specify Requirement **will not compile**.

(Emphasis mine).

Either use `throws` to allow your method to throw this exception (causing your application to terminate):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
```

or catch it:

```
try {
   ...
} catch ( IOException e ) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Why its throwing exception? how to run it without exception throwing?

Comment: @Webroots: You **can't** run it until it's a **valid** Java program. It's not valid until you either *catch* the checked exception or specify that your method *throws* this exception. This is just a requirement of the Java langauge and you have to accept that or use a different language. (C# for example is quite similar to Java but *doesn't* have this requirement). **Your program is currently not a valid Java program**. Once you have a valid, compiling program *then* you can run it.

Comment: That is "Checked Exception".The method you called "br.readline()" will throw an exception(perhaps not) so you need to catch it to make sure your program continue. That is a rule.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend reading the ["Exceptions"](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html) chapter of the Java tutorial (and the rest, too, by the way).